# Streaming video using Windows RT?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, ftp, windows-rt

I'm trying to stream video in my C# Windows RT app for Windows 8. I want to do this through FTP. Let's say I have a stream open to the file that I want to view, or some kind of buffer.

How do I send this on to Windows 8, so that it can display my video?

What would be the best approach? Note that I don't want to download the file first. I want to stream it live.

Comment: Ugh. Why FTP? FTP is unreliable because it depends on complicated TCP connections and different port values making firewalling hard. What's wrong with HTTP?

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to the recourses though HTTP